# Makefile dependencies without triggering dependent rules

Tags: makefile

If I have a target, that has some dependencies, and I invoke that target, `make` will try and generate the dependencies if the relevant rules are available (they are). Is there any way to prevent this behaviour, essentially telling `make` that to use that target the dependencies must be available, but to just error out if they aren't?

Example, assuming that `foo` and `bar` do not exist:

```
foo:
    echo a > foo

bar:
    echo b > bar

target: foo bar
    cat foo bar > foobar
```

**Desired behaviour**

```
> make target
error, cannot satisfy dependencies
```

**Actual behaviour**

```
> make target
echo a > foo
echo b > bar
cat foo bar > foobar
```

GNU make is being used, if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  If make cannot find a rule to build a prerequisite, and it doesn't exist, then make will fail.  If make CAN find a rule to build a prerequisite, and it's out of date, then make will build it.

If you don't want it rebuilt, you should not list it as a prerequisite.  You can do something like this:

```
target:
        [ -f foo ] && [ -f bar ] || { echo "cannot satisfy prerequisites"; exit 1; }
```

Comment: That's a shame, but I expected it.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is something like

```
target: dependency

dependency:
        @echo fatal error: $@ is missing; exit 1
```